# Workflow HTTP PUT request error

Tags: workflow, error, rest

Receiving this error when trying to update a list item via HTTP PUT in SPD Workflow:

> error":{"code":"-1,
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"The
>   type SP.ListItem does not support HTTP PUT method}